# Office JavaScript API: Hiding the title of a bound ContentControl

Tags: office-js

Using the Office JavaScript API in MS Word, I am binding a `ContentControl` by using its `title` property. This works fine, but Word displays this title, causing confusion for end users. I am wondering if there is a way to prevent the title from being shown.

[image: A ContentControl with title being displayed.]

*Current result: a `ContentControl` which displays its custom title `cc_typo5`.*

[image: A ContentControl without title being displayed.]

*Desired result: a `ContentControl` which doesn't display its custom title `cc_typo5`.*

Answer (score 1):

That's just how content controls work in Word, but you have an alternative:
Have you tried making the content control invisible?
Check out this code:

```js
Word.run(function (context) {
        context.document.contentControls.getByTitle("cc_typo5").getFirst().appearance = "hidden";
        return context.sync(); 
    })
        .catch(OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log);
```